# How to apply JQuery function on Javascript HTMLDocument object

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am facing with a JavaScript HTMLDocument & JQuery related problem.

I have following div in my HTML page:

```
<div id="description21" class="comment1">

</div>
```

When I apply a JQuery library function, it works fine:

```
$('.comment1').readmore({speed: 500});
```

However the actual issue is that, I am trying to do this to a HTMLDocument object.

I have a string object in JS containing html, which I convert to HTMLDocument

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/html");
```

After that I find the  containing the class name 'comment1':

```
var commentDiv = doc.getElementsByClassName('comment1');
```

Then, I want to apply the same Jquery method as mentioned above to this div:

```
$(commentDiv[0]).readmore({speed: 500});
```

But, when I check my html, the changes are not getting applied.

```
alert(doc.documentElement.innerHTML);
```

How can I apply the jQuery function to the `HTMLDocumentelement`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need delegation to achieve that.

Comment: what does the readmore plugin do?

Comment: Melancia, how to achieve delegation in this case?

Comment: Daniel, the readmore will check the text content inside the div, if it is more than configured value, it will create a 'read more' link and hide the rest of the text, more like 'show more' 'show less' kind of functionality.

Comment: Where you are writing new string in HTML?Looks like you need to add
document.getElementById(description21).innerHTML = doc

Comment: @MelanciaUK initializing a plugin doesn't really fall into `event delegation`. The plugin could be rewritten for delegation but there is no reason it can't be initialized after dom insertion either

Comment: where's the code that inserts the html into the DOM? Can Initialize plugin after insertion

Comment: @MelanciaUK here is the code:                                                               $("#content #main-sidebar-container #main #box").html(doc.documentElement.innerHTML);

Comment: But, If the 'readmore' changes were applied, I shoud be able to see throught the alert, but I am not able to. How can I handle this?